# url params not making it to my landing page with angular app

Tags: angular, routeparams

when testing on localhost everything works great:

`http://localhost:4200/#/?referralId=1`

the url stays in the bowser and I am able to access my params. But when I upload the app to the server and I go to this url:

`https://www.betradating.com?referralId=1`

the browser is refreshing automatically, losing the params and displaying:

`https://www.betradating.com/#`

How can I fix this?

Comment: It could be an issue with your hosting config.  Maybe you have a url rewrite configured or something along those lines.

Answer (score 0):

> http://localhost:4200/#/?referralId=1

It looks like you're using HashLocationStrategy?

> https://www.betradating.com?referralId=1

You must add a `<base href>` element to the application's **index.html** for this type of HTML5 routing to work (pushState routing).

Add the <base> element within the <head> tag:

```
<head>
  <meta>...
  <title>...
  <base href="/">
```

Answer (score 0):

turns out I needed the hash character in the url for it to work:

`https://www.betradating.com/#/?referralId=1`